# AccessViolationException when using FileRead API

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I am using the FileRead API.
I used Windows 7 x64 and my code worked good and correct.
Now I installed a new Windows 7 x86 and VS2008 teamsuit and .NET 2, 3+SP1+SP2, 3.5, 3.5.1.
I run my code as Administrator but still encounter the follwoing error:

> AccessViolationException(Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.)

```
 int nread = 0;
 uint handle;
 byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
 string driveRoot = string.Concat("\\\\.\\", driveLetter);
 uint hRoot = CreateFile(driveRoot,
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                IntPtr.Zero);
 if (hRoot != -1)
      handle = ReadFile(hRoot, buff, 1024, nread, new System.Threading.NativeOverlapped());
```

Comment: Your HANDLEs should be IntPtr but that won't be a problem on x86. Should have been a problem on x64 though. And nread is passed as a pointer too, you are passing a uint. Should also be an IntPtr.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm no C# guru, it appears to me that you're invoking `ReadFile()` with wrong parameters.

The 4th parameter must be a pointer to an integer that will receive the number of bytes read. You supply the integer itself (`nread`), not its address (`&nread`).

And unless you want asynchronous file I/O, the last parameter to `ReadFile()` must be a NULL pointer (or just 0).

See [this example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: but it work correctly on windows7 x64!!!
why the same code couldn't work properly on windows7 x86???
what's the problem?

Comment: nread probably works out because win32 expects a pointer and passing zero int equates to NULL pointer.

Comment: I think the overlapped read could be an issue. You definitely don't want overlapped here. That could result in writes to the buffer long after the buffer has been deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the main problem with your code is that you are requesting overlapped I/O but supplying a buffer that ceases to exist when `ReadFile` returns. It works on some systems an not others because the system decides whether or not to perform the operation asynchronously, and it may choose not to do async on one system and choose differently on another.

I'm sure you don't want overlapped I/O so you should simply pass `NULL` to the final parameter of `ReadFile`.

On the other hand, perhaps your code isn't working at all on the x64 system and never gets as far as an AV. Your handle types are mis-declared as 32 bit integers.

There are many other minor problems with your code. Here's an edited version of the code that corrects these errors. The P/invoke signatures were taken from pinvoke.net.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
    string lpFileName,
    uint dwDesiredAccess,
    uint dwShareMode,
    IntPtr SecurityAttributes,
    uint dwCreationDisposition,
    uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile
);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ReadFile(
    IntPtr hFile, 
    [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
    uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, 
    out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, 
    IntPtr lpOverlapped
);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string physicalDrive = @"\\.\PhysicalDrive0";
    IntPtr hFile = CreateFile(
        physicalDrive, 
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        IntPtr.Zero
    );
    if (hFile.ToInt64() != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        uint nread;
        if (ReadFile(hFile, buff, (uint)buff.Length, out nread, IntPtr.Zero))
            Console.WriteLine("Read successful");
    }
}
```

To summarise the errors in your code:

- Incorrect use of 32 bit integers to store handles.
- Your P/invoke declaration of `ReadFile` declares the `lpNumberOfBytesRead` incorrectly.
- `ReadFile` does not return a handle, it returns a boolean indicating success of the function call.
- Use of overlapped I/O which you do not want, and which cannot work with a marshalled `byte[]` buffer.
- You must never call `GetLastError` from managed code (you did so in code shown in a comment). Instead call [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx). The reasons are explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) for that method.

Comment: tnx for edit.now i moved to offset from hfile with SetFilePointerEx.i did this but it dont work currectly ==> SetFilePointerEx(hRoot, MFTAddress, ref newaddress, 0);
int error = GetLastError();
    if (hRoot != IntPtr.Zero)
handle = ReadFile(hRoot, buff, 1024,ref nread, new System.Threading.NativeOverlapped());</br>

Comment: @Saeed I think I answered your original question. Now you appear to be asking a different question in your comment. You did not say in what way it failed. "It don't work correctly" is never enough information for us to help you. What's more, supplying code in comments does not help since it is never formatted in a readable way. Questions can be edited, new questions can be asked. For the record, did my answer solve your original problem?

Comment: Now, looking at the code in the comment I can see two problems. Never ever call `GetLastError` from managed code. Call [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) The documentation explains why this is important. Secondly, please stop asking for overlapped I/O. You don't want it, and it can't work with P/invoke byte[] buffers. Thirdly, `ReadFile` does not return a handle, it returns a `bool`. I already showed you all this in my answer.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make it clear in my answer that there was lots wrong with your code. Look at how your code differs from mine. Look at your P/invoke signatures and look at mine. See how they differ. I've added some text at the bottom of the answer to spell out all the errors I identified in your code.

Comment: my code work correctly on Win7 x64.it don't work on win7 x86.I forgot about win7 x86 completely.now this is the main problem :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374386/setfilepointerex-api-to-read-mft

Comment: The code was just as wrong on x64. You just got lucky. Your experience on x86 is know as "luck running out". Your new question contains the same errors that I already fixed in this answer.