# SetFilePointerEx API to read MFT

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I want to read some bytes from MFT offset on a partition. I got partition handle and read first 1K bytes successfully, but `SetFilePointerEx` returns an error. Please help me with it.

```
int nread = 0;
IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
IntPtr newaddress = IntPtr.Zero;
long MFTAddress = bytepersector * sectorpercluster * (long)MFTStart;
string driveRoot = "\\\\.\\c:";

IntPtr hRoot = CreateFile(driveRoot,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    IntPtr.Zero);

SetFilePointerEx(hRoot, MFTAddress, ref newaddress, 0);

int error = GetLastError();
if (hRoot != IntPtr.Zero)
    handle = ReadFile(newaddress, buff, 1024,ref nread, new System.Threading.NativeOverlapped());
```

---

this is code that found MFTOffset and other information.

```
            uint nread = 0;
        IntPtr handle;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        string driveRoot = string.Concat("\\\\.\\", driveLetter);
        IntPtr hRoot = CreateFile(driveRoot,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            IntPtr.Zero);
        if (hRoot != IntPtr.Zero)
             ReadFile(hRoot, buff, 1024,out nread, IntPtr.Zero);
        string SystemFile = Convert.ToString(LittleEndian(4, new byte[] { buff[3], buff[4], buff[5], buff[6] }, typeof(string)));
        int BytePerSector = 0;
        int SectorPerCluster = 0;
        double MFTStart = 0;
        if (SystemFile == "NTFS")
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(SystemFile);

            BytePerSector = (int)LittleEndian(2, new byte[] { buff[11], buff[12] }, BytePerSector.GetType());
            listBox1.Items.Add("Byte per Sector : " + BytePerSector);

            SectorPerCluster = (int)LittleEndian(1, new byte[] { buff[13] }, typeof(int));
            listBox1.Items.Add("Sector per Cluster : " + SectorPerCluster.ToString());

            MFTStart = (long)LittleEndian(8, new byte[]{
                buff[48],buff[49],buff[50],buff[51],buff[52],buff[53],buff[54],buff[55]}, typeof(long));
            listBox1.Items.Add("MFT LCN : " + MFTStart);

        }
        else
            listBox1.Items.Add("No NTFS Valoume");
```

I wanna read MFT.I found its offset on partition.i got partition handle with CreateFile API then i got MFT offset from MBR with ReadFile API.i compared result with WinHex and result was correct.now i wanna move to mft address on partition.i found SetFilePointer API to do it.
i used SetFilePointer but i got error while use ReadFile(newAddress)

```
public static void ReadMFT(string DriveLetter, ulong MFTStart, int bytepersector, int sectorpercluster)
    {
        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr newaddress = IntPtr.Zero;
        long MFTAddress = bytepersector * sectorpercluster * (long)MFTStart;
        string driveRoot = string.Concat("\\\\.\\", DriveLetter);
        IntPtr hRoot = CreateFile(driveRoot,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        **newaddress = SetFilePointer(hRoot, (ulong)MFTAddress, IntPtr.Zero, 0);**
        Console.WriteLine("hroot : " + hRoot.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("MFTAddress : " + MFTAddress.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("NewAddress : " + newaddress.ToString());
        if (hRoot.ToInt64() != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            uint nread;
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            if (**ReadFile(newaddress, buff, (uint)buff.Length, out nread, IntPtr.Zero)**)
                Console.WriteLine("Read successful");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Read unsuccessful");

        }
        while (true)
        {
            //read other MFT Record
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Saeed, can you show the P/Invoke declaration that you used for SetFilePointerEX and share with us what error you are getting?

Comment: the return value of ReadFile is zero (FALSE)=Error.MFTAddress is currect.did i write SetFilePointerEx function currectly?

Comment: This code contains practically all the errors I pointed out in your previous question. Why do you ask for help and then ignore that help.

Comment: sorry David.bcz i am in hurry.i have no time.i have to finish my project till tomorrow.sorry again.

Comment: Not fixing errors is not going to save you time.

Answer (score 2):

I can see the following errors:

- You are not checking the return value of `CreateFile` for success or failure.
- You are passing the wrong thing to the first parameter of `ReadFile`. You need to pass the handle to the file.
- You use overlapped I/O which you do not want, and which cannot work with a marshalled `byte[]` buffer. Pass `IntPtr.Zero` for `lpOverlapped` or perhaps `null` depending on how your P/invoke is declared.
- `ReadFile` does not return a handle, it returns a boolean indicating success of the function call.
- You must never call `GetLastError` from managed code. Instead call [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx). The reasons are explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) for that method.
- Do not call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` unless the prior API call actually failed. You did not check whether or not [`SetFilePointerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) succeeded. Just like `ReadFile`, it returns a boolean to indicate success or failure.

Comment: In addition to your points, ReadFile's arguments are incorrect, the first argument should be the file handle, the OP is passing the newAddress which is the file pointer position. OP is not checking the value of hRoot before calling SetFilePointerEx.

Comment: @Chris Thanks. I've udpated. This list was actually copied from my answer to the previous question!! In that question, I think that there were even fewer mistakes than in this question!!!

Comment: dear David.I wanna read MFT.I found its offset on partition.i got partition handle with CreateFile API then i got MFT offset from MBR with ReadFile API.i compared result with WinHex and result was correct.now i wanna move to mft address on partition.i found SetFilePointer API to do it.could u send me correct code to move MFT offset??

Comment: I suggest you fix the errors as described in my answer. But, without wishing to appear rude, reading the MFT is no trivial business. Is managed code with P/invokes the best route to do this? And I wonder if you should consider a simpler project to bring yourself fully up-to-speed with the intricacies of win32.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (section ***Physical Disks and Volumes***), if you want to access the partition table, you must use [`DeviceIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Restrictions and requirements apply starting from Windows Vista.

An example linked from the documentation: [Calling DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I believe you've misread that documentation.  It does not say that you cannot use ReadFile/WriteFile on a disk or volume handle.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Well, that may be true. I went the least confusing way. There is documentation on how exactly `DeviceIoControl` would return something, whereas I can't find a word about what `ReadFile` would return when presented with a DASD handle instead of a file system handle.

Comment: It does exactly as you'd expect, presenting the raw contents of the disk or volume as if it were a single file.  Anyway, I think you've misread the question: he's trying to read the Master File Table (MFT) not the Master Boot Record (MBR).